# Sanity.io - Image URL exposure for preview/select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system, sanity

I have been using and enjoying Sanity and am currently doing a reasonable sized CMS build with this. I am attempting to set some "preview" images for a gallery of images (using type array).
Having trawled through the docs I am unable to find the solution I am looking for - and judging by their usage of the `preview` setting in the schema I am unable to replicate the same usage of `image.asset.url` as it is not in the object when logged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I assume theres a configuration issue or a package I may not have that helps to expose this. But after looking at multiple Sanity Test Repo's, none have anything that sticks out.

Schema Code.

```
export default {
    name: "imageSliderBlock",
    type: "object",
    title: "Image Slider Block",
    fields: [
        {
            name: "slider",
            type: "array",
            title: "Slider",
            options: {
                layout: 'grid'
            },
            of: [
                {
                    // These are the images I am attempting to query
                    name: "image",
                    type: "image",
                    title: "Slide Image",
                    options: {
                        hotspot: true,
                    },
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: "alt",
                            type: "string",
                            title: "Alternative Text",
                            validation: Rule => Rule.error('You have to fill out the alternative text.').required(),
                            options: {
                                isHighlighted: true,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    preview: {
        select: {
            // This is the query that should work
            // It should find the first array index within the name:slider
            // and grab the asset url within the object.
            media: 'slider.0.asset.url'
        },
        prepare: ({media}) => {
            // Returns only asset._ref and asset._type:reference
            console.log(media);
            return {
                title: "Image Slider Block",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The following is the `console.log()` from calling > `media: slider.0` to show the object (as obviously the above schema won't work as I have stated theres no `asset.url` in the object.

```
{_type: "image", asset: {…}}
asset:
_ref: "image-cd7896b89af6cbd0feb9d47dc1ebd6cff396f400-1755x1241-png"
_type: "reference"
__proto__: Object
_type: "image"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:

So the docs seem either a little outdated from a change that may have happened, or I was attempting to do something slightly different from the example.

```
  preview: {
        select: {
            image: 'slider.0.asset',
        },
        prepare: ({image}) => {
            return {
                title: 'Slider Block',
                media: image
            }
        }
    }
```

rather than passing the URL to an `<img>` JSX component, you pass the entire `asset` object for the image you wish to use to `media:`  and it must use the `_ref` and `_type` to decipher what image it is.

Very odd - but resolved

Comment: Do you have an idea, how i would do it to display two images?

Comment: @vinni - try duplicating select:image as select:imageTwo: 'slider.1.asset' if its the second in array. then try doing in prepare media: [image, imageTwo]

Comment: If it doesn't work as thats just a "spitballing" idea, you may need to create a custom component in place of media that takes in those two images and displays them both together